# I'm having trouble using an excel function

Tags: excel

The function I am trying to use is:

```
=G6^-6+H6^-9*-200+I6^-6*1
```

Where the `G6` cell should be multipled to the -6th power then add the value in cell `H6` to the -9th power then multiplied by -200 then add `I6` cell to the -6th power then everything is multiplied by 1 (for now it doesn't need to be there since it wouldn't change the value but I will need to use other values later).

When I try my function as is the result I get is `#DIV/0!`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well 0^-n where n is some number seems to get you  #DIV/0!. So if any of G6, H6, or I6 is zero you get #DIV/0!. Is this helpful or I don't understand your question?

Answer (score 2):

Try `=(POWER(G6,-6)+POWER(H6,-9))*-200+POWER(I6,-6)` (see [POWER function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/power-function-HP010342773.aspx)). The mathematical hierarchy you described in your original post requires some brackets but using the `POWER` function can eliminate many of them by isolating the exponents.